# Composer update/install not installing or updating anything

Tags: php, composer-php

today I've tried to install components in an PHP project through composer. This way I can install all the dependencies.

But it doesn't show anything getting installed or being updated. Even when I git clone the project from scratch and then do a composer install nothing gets installed. There is no vendor folder after executing the command.

```
 php ~/bin/composer.phar install
```

[image]

What goes wrong here?

Comment: try `php ~/bin/composer.phar install -vvv`. it should give you some info

Comment: Yeah I did but it doesn't give me any errors :/

Answer (score 0):

Seems a problem related to user permission, try with the [diagnose](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#diagnose) command:

```
php ~/bin/composer.phar diagnose
```

and see what happen. Hope this help

Comment: Thanks @Federico is a typo. Feeling free to edit my answer